# How to know if BlackBerry device has GPS?

Tags: blackberry, geolocation

I want to know if the device has GPS or not, how could I do that for the devices below v 5.0 ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Have a look at docs for [`Location Provider`](http://www.blackberry.com/developers/docs/4.6.0api/javax/microedition/location/LocationProvider.html). Try this code on a few devices in different situations and I think it should work:

```
try {
    LocationProvider lp = LocationProvider.getInstance(null);
    if (lp == null) {
        //Device doesn't currently have GPS enabled
    } else {
        //Device has GPS enabled
    }
} catch (LocationException le) {
     //Device's GPS is currently permanently disabled
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to [check if Java ME's JSR 179 is available](http://docs.blackberry.com/en/developers/deliverables/17954/GPS_overview_857606_11.jsp).