# Check if BlackBerry gps is enabled

Tags: blackberry, gps

I am developing an app in which I have to check programmatically if gps is enabled or not for locations in phone? How do I find this?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to know if BlackBerry device has GPS ?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4400976/how-to-know-if-blackberry-device-has-gps)

Answer (score 1):

```
if (!LocationInfo.isLocationOn()) {
    try {
        LocationInfo.setLocationOn();
    } catch (ControlledAccessException cae) {
        // You don't have the rights to enable GPS programatically.
        // You might want to prompt the user for it.
    }
}
```

You might also want to have a look at the following functions:

- LocationInfo.isLocationSourceAvailable(int mode) -
        Determines if a specific location source is available to provide location information.
- LocationInfo.isLocationSourceSupported(int mode) -
        Determines if a specific location source is currently supported on the device.

gl

Answer (score -1):

All new BB have on device GPS.  You just need to make sure it is set correctly.

First make sure you set GPS Data Source == Device GPS in the Options->Advanced Options app.