# How to change wifi enable and disable programatically

Tags: blackberry

I have to set some blackberry device settings by coding.
Like.
1. Activate call waiting.
2. Enable wifi.
3. Enable GPS.

Can somebody help me. hope my question is clear

Comment: Why you want to enable wifi or GPS? for what purposes? You mean for establishing a connection or what?

Comment: What research have you done on enabling these features from code?

Comment: Hi Farid Farhat, I want to create app. who will show weather gps is enabled. and provide a interactivity so user can enable and disable, GPS,Bluetooth,wifi    thanx.

Comment: Hi Michael Donohue, I have Googled for it but don't found any help anywhere.

Comment: Here is how you can turn on GPS in code: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4632907/check-if-blackberry-gps-is-enabled/8051403#8051403

Comment: Hi finally you can got any solution of this? I need same as your que. if you have any solution of enable or desable GPS,Bluetooth and wifi. than please send.

Answer (score 0):

// call

```
Radio.activateWAFs(RadioInfo.WAF_WLAN);
```