# Blackberry code to check whether GPS is on or off in the phone

Tags: blackberry-eclipse-plugin

I want the code to check whether GPS in my phone ids on or off?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [Location Provider](http://www.blackberry.com/developers/docs/4.6.0api/javax/microedition/location/LocationProvider.html) :

```
    try {
    LocationProvider lp = LocationProvider.getInstance(null);
    if (lp == null) {
        //Device doesn't currently have GPS enabled
    } else {
        //Device has GPS enabled
    }
} catch (LocationException le) {
     //Device's GPS is currently permanently disabled
}
```

Credit: [aligf](https://stackoverflow.com/users/529508/aligf)

[Similar Question.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4400976/how-to-know-if-blackberry-device-has-gps)